# Adding a doubletap gesture in Swift to both edit and endEditing

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to add a doubleTap gesture to a UIButton that edits a UITextField and when finished you can double tap again to enable the endEditing function. Is there a way you can do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can just check the state of the text field and do something similar to this:

```
if textField.isFirstResponder() { textField.becomeFirstResponder() }
else                            { textField.resignFirstResponder() }
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a tap gesture accept two taps (if you are using interface builder), select the tap gesture recognizer in the view hierarchy

[image]

Then using the attributes inspector, select the number of tap to be two

[image]